# Dll Injection - CreateRemoteThread dll not showing message box

Tags: c++, dll, dll-injection

I'm trying some DLL injections but I have some problems :/
When I run this program I get the message "Remote Thread Created", so everything should works ok and the DLL should be loaded. But the DLL doesn't show any messageBox (it should just show a message box when loaded)

This is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[]){

    char buffer[] = "C:\\drivers\\inject.dll";

    int procID = 1056;
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, procID);
    if(process == NULL){
        printf("Cannot get handle to process.");
        getchar();
        return -0x1;
    }

    LPVOID addr = (LPVOID) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    if(addr == NULL){
        prinf("Cannot get address of function \'LoadLibraryA\'.");
        getchar();
        return -0x1;
    }

    LPVOID arg = (LPVOID) VirtualAllocEx(process, NULL, strlen(buffer), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if(arg == NULL){
        printf("Cannote write memory.");
        getchar();
        return -0x1;
    }

    int n = WriteProcessMemory(process, arg, buffer, strlen(buffer), NULL);
    if(n == 0x0){
        printf("Cannot write on process address space.");
        getchar();
        return -0x1;
    }

    HANDLE threadID = CreateRemoteThread(process, NULL, 0x0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) addr, arg, NULL, NULL);
    if(threadID == NULL){
        printf("Cannot create remote thread.");
        getchar();
        return -0x1;
    } else {
        printf("Remote Thread Created.\n");
    }

    CloseHandle(process);
    getchar();

    return 0x0;
}
```

DLL (.cpp):

```
#define BUILD_DLL
#include "simple_dll.h"

// a sample exported function
void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, sometext, "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

extern "C" DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            SomeFunction("DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH");
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            SomeFunction("DLL_PROCESS_DETACH");
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            SomeFunction("DLL_THREAD_ATTACH");
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            SomeFunction("DLL_THREAD_DETACH");
            break;
    }
    return TRUE; // succesful
}
```

DLL (.h):

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <windows.h>

/*  To use this exported function of dll, include this header
 *  in your project.
 */

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
    #endif

    void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

Can someone please explain me why I don't get the messagebox?

Answer (score 1):

First off, [`MessageBoxA()` is not safe to call in `DllMain()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices).

> You should never perform the following tasks from within DllMain:
>
> ...
>
> - **Call functions in User32.dll** or Gdi32.dll. Some functions load another DLL, which may not be initialized.
>
> ...

In any case, just because `CreateRemoteThread()` succeeds in creating a remote thread does not guarantee that `LoadLibraryA()` will succeed when the remote thread calls it. Which, in this situation, is likely the culprit, because the DLL path string you are allocating in the remote process is not null-terminated properly, so `LoadLibraryA()` is likely failing.  You need to use `strlen(buffer)+1` when allocating the string and when copying the characters into it.

Also, not related to your problem, but if `VirtualAllocEx()` succeeds, regardless of whatever happens with the remote thread, you need to free the allocated string when you are done using it, or else it will be leaked. Also, don't use `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`, that is way too many permissions to ask for, you should request only the specific permissions you actually need.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[]){

    const char buffer[] = "C:\\drivers\\inject.dll";
    const size_t bufferSize = strlen(buffer) + 1;

    int procID = 1056;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, procID);
    if (hProcess == NULL){
        printf("Cannot get handle to process.");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    LPVOID addr = (LPVOID) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    if (addr == NULL){
        prinf("Cannot get address of function \'LoadLibraryA\'.");
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    LPVOID arg = (LPVOID) VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, bufferSize, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (arg == NULL){
        printf("Cannote allocate memory in process address space.");
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    BOOL n = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, arg, buffer, bufferSize, NULL);
    if (n == FALSE){
        printf("Cannot write to process address space.");
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, arg, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) addr, arg, NULL, NULL);
    if (hThread == NULL){
        printf("Cannot create remote thread.");
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, arg, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Remote Thread Created.\n");

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);

    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, arg, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tryed to add 1 to the bufferSize but nothing changes the MessageBox doesn't appear.
Where should I perform MessageBoxA()? Do you mean to perform it inside another function?

Comment: @Z3R0 you *could* have `DllMain()` create a local thread just to call `MessageBox()` (just don't let `DllMain()` wait on that thread). But personally, I would not use `MessageBox()` at all. I would make the DLL write to a log file instead. Or use `OutputDebugString()`, and then use [SysInternals DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to see the message.

Comment: I changed so now the DLL writes a file, but nothing happens when I launch the program that should inject the DLL. Looks like the DLL is not loaded.

Comment: @Z3R0 then you are just going to have to debug it to find out why it is failing. Does the remote process have permission to access the DLL? Is the DLL using the same bit size as the remote process? You may need to expand your allocated memory to include a minimum bit of actual executable code to capture the return value and error code of `LoadLibraryA()` so your Launcher can read them with `ReadProcessMemory()`.

Comment: Ok I will try to debug it. How can I find if the remote process has the permission to access the DLL? Also what do you mean whit "Is the DLL using the same bit size as the remote process?", like if the DLL is big as the remote process so when it try to set memory inside the process it doesn't have enough space?

Comment: @Z3R0 "*what do you mean whit "Is the DLL using the same bit size as the remote process?"*" - meaning, is the DLL compiled as 32bit or 64bit, and is the remote process a 32bit or 64bit app? You can't load a 32bit DLL into a 64bit process, or a 64bit DLL into a 32bit process.

Comment: Oh ok, I tryed to compiled them both 32 bit and 64 bit.